# Groovy update xml list of lists to lists on condition preserving other objects

Tags: xml, list, groovy

I'm trying this in groovy.

simple **input.xml**

```
<response>
    <quote>
        <alpha>
            <a>1</a>
            <b>2</b>
        </alpha>
        <beta>
            <gama>
                <a1>12</a1>
                <a2>13</a2>
            </gama>
            <specifics>
                <key>fname</key>
                <value>Tom</value>
            </specifics>
            <specifics>
                <key>lname</key>
                <value>Cruise</value>
            </specifics>
            <specifics>
                <key>phone</key>
                <value>12345</value>
            </specifics>
            <specifics>
                <key>address</key>
                <value>NewYork</value>
            </specifics>
        </beta>
    </quote>
</response>
```

Expected **output.xml**

```
<response>
    <quote>
        <alpha>
            <a>1</a>
            <b>2</b>
        </alpha>
        <beta>
            <gama>
                <a1>12</a1>
                <a2>13</a2>
            </gama>
            <specifics>
                <fname>Tom</fname>
                <lname>Cruise</lname>
                <phone>12345</phone>
                <address>newYork</address>
            </specifics>
        </beta>
    </quote>
</response>
```

What I'm trying to do here is to preserve the complete xml object as such but with one modification. As you see, the `specifics` tag is a list so it repeats many times. However, each `specifics` tag has only `key` and `value` inside it. The condition is look for tag `specifics` and remove `key` and `value` tags and add one element with key as value of element `key` and value as value of element `value`.

I tried using groovy collect somewhat like this

```
data.collect { "$it.key $it.value" }
```

but ended up in loosing other elements. In my case, all other elements should exist in the output with modifications to this `specifics` tag. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def x=new XmlParser().parseText('''<response>
    <quote>
        <alpha>
            <a>1</a>
            <b>2</b>
        </alpha>
        <beta>
            <gama>
                <a1>12</a1>
                <a2>13</a2>
            </gama>
            <specifics>
                <key>fname</key>
                <value>Tom</value>
            </specifics>
            <specifics>
                <key>lname</key>
                <value>Cruise</value>
            </specifics>
            <specifics>
                <key>phone</key>
                <value>12345</value>
            </specifics>
            <specifics>
                <key>address</key>
                <value>NewYork</value>
            </specifics>
        </beta>
    </quote>
</response>''')
```

v1

```groovy
//this variant almost do the job except creating parent for all specifics
x.quote.beta.specifics.each{spec->
    spec.replaceNode { "${spec.key.text()}"( spec.value.text() ) }
}
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(x)
```

```xml
...
<beta>
  <gama>
    <a1>12</a1>
    <a2>13</a2>
  </gama>
  <fname>Tom</fname>
  <lname>Cruise</lname>
  <phone>12345</phone>
  <address>NewYork</address>
</beta>
```

v2
almost the same as previous

```groovy
x.quote.beta.specifics.each{spec->
    spec.replaceNode { "specifics"( "key":spec.key.text(),  spec.value.text() ) }
}
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(x)
```

```xml
<beta>
  <gama>
    <a1>12</a1>
    <a2>13</a2>
  </gama>
  <specifics key="fname">Tom</specifics>
  <specifics key="lname">Cruise</specifics>
  <specifics key="phone">12345</specifics>
  <specifics key="address">NewYork</specifics>
</beta>
```

v3 the required result

```groovy
Node newspec = new Node(null,"specifics")
x.quote.beta.specifics.each{spec->
    newspec.appendNode("${spec.key.text()}", null, spec.value.text() )
    spec.parent().remove(spec)
}
x.quote.beta[0].append(newspec)
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(x)
```